# Is Wi-Fi Adhoc Mode operation supported in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, adhoc

I am fairly new to Android and I am trying to use Wi-Fi Adhoc Mode in my application. But I could not find any API or method to set the same. I read a thread in Android Forum and could not come any concrete solution on how to use enable Adhoc mode in Android.I used to use WPA_Supplicant conf file in Linux to enable Adhoc mode.

I would like know if I can enable Wi-Fi Adhoc mode in Android from my application and how to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  It's instructions for the HTC Hero (android device) and shows how to modify tiwlan.ini and wpa_supplicant.conf to enable ad-hoc wifi.

http://blog.joint.net/2009/07/connecting-android-phone-through-adhoc.html?showComment=1277115947367#c3774826726667256208

And for what to add to the tiwlan and wpasupplicant files, see here:

http://modmymobile.com/forums/491-root-access/544146-connect-g1-ad-hoc-network-solved.html

Presumably you recognise the adb commands - these are just for transferring the files to and from the device from your development PC and then remount the /system partition - you would probably want to do this programmatically instead.  Should be doable with superuser access, dunno if it's possible without.

Comment: Thank You for the information , I will try enabling it using root access.

Comment: Updated links now.  Note that I have no idea how modern phones differ to the HTC Hero (I wrote this 4 years ago), hope it helps though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported currently but the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82) has been accepted and should be available in the future.

The file that would need to be modified to make it work is /system/etc/wifi/tiwlan.ini, like thomasrutter mentioned, but it will require root access to modify the file.

Comment: Thank You for the information , I will try enabling it using root access.

Comment: Here are the relevant issues: 

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41502

Can't hurt to star them.